# Clean tin with aluminium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, redox

I've been using aluminium foil and table salt to clean my silverware for a long time without actually concerning myself with the chemistry behind it. A couple of days ago i started digging into the chemistry and found this page on wikipedia

[Reactivity series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactivity_series)

and when I looked closer i saw that both silver and tin where less reactive than aluminium. Does that mean that I can safely use the same technique with my tinware as with my silverware?